# SQL Server 2012 SqlTableDependency trigger on my table "locks" all upcoming DML operations

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I enable Service Broker in my SQL Server 2012 to use `SqlTableDependency` in vb.net application to notify me on update of a column.

But recently I saw a trigger on my table which "locks" all upcoming DML operations to this table.

The error message is when I trying to update the field

> No row was updated.
> Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data provider.
> Error Message: Cannot find object ID 467661280 in database ID 49.
> Correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the change(s).

I disable the trigger `tr_dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender` and the locks goes away. So why does this happen and how to avoid it again?

This is the trigger which automatically generated:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender] 
ON [dbo].[Appointments] 
WITH EXECUTE AS SELF
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @rowsToProcess INT
    DECLARE @currentRow INT
    DECLARE @records XML
    DECLARE @theMessageContainer NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @dmlType NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @modifiedRecordsTable TABLE ([RowNumber] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [UniqueID] int, [lngContact] nvarchar(50), [StartDate] smalldatetime, [Status] int)
    DECLARE @exceptTable TABLE ([RowNumber] INT, [UniqueID] int, [lngContact] nvarchar(50), [StartDate] smalldatetime, [Status] int)
    DECLARE @deletedTable TABLE ([RowNumber] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [UniqueID] int, [lngContact] nvarchar(50), [StartDate] smalldatetime, [Status] int)
    DECLARE @insertedTable TABLE ([RowNumber] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [UniqueID] int, [lngContact] nvarchar(50), [StartDate] smalldatetime, [Status] int)
    DECLARE @var1 int
    DECLARE @var2 nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @var3 smalldatetime
    DECLARE @var4 int

    DECLARE @conversationHandlerExists INT
    SELECT @conversationHandlerExists = COUNT(*) FROM sys.conversation_endpoints WHERE conversation_handle = '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa';
    IF @conversationHandlerExists = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @conversation_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
        DECLARE @schema_id INT;
        SELECT @schema_id = schema_id FROM sys.schemas WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo';

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tr_dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender]')) DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender];

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE schema_id = @schema_id AND name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender') EXEC (N'ALTER QUEUE [dbo].[dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender] WITH ACTIVATION (STATUS = OFF)');

        
        SELECT conversation_handle INTO #Conversations FROM sys.conversation_endpoints WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE far_service LIKE N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_%' ORDER BY is_initiator ASC;
        DECLARE conversation_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT conversation_handle FROM #Conversations;
        OPEN conversation_cursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM conversation_cursor INTO @conversation_handle;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            END CONVERSATION @conversation_handle WITH CLEANUP;
            FETCH NEXT FROM conversation_cursor INTO @conversation_handle;
        END
        CLOSE conversation_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE conversation_cursor;
        DROP TABLE #Conversations;

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.services WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Receiver') DROP SERVICE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Receiver];
        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.services WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender') DROP SERVICE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender];

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE schema_id = @schema_id AND name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Receiver') DROP QUEUE [dbo].[dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Receiver];
        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE schema_id = @schema_id AND name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender') DROP QUEUE [dbo].[dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_Sender];

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_contracts WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3') DROP CONTRACT [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3];
        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Insert') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Insert];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Update') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Update];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Delete') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Delete];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/UniqueID') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/UniqueID];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/lngContact') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/lngContact];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartDate') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartDate];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/Status') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/Status];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/EndMessage') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/EndMessage];

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE schema_id = @schema_id AND name = N'dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_QueueActivationSender') DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3_QueueActivationSender];
        RETURN
    END
    
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN
        SET @dmlType = 'Delete'
        INSERT INTO @modifiedRecordsTable SELECT [UniqueID], [lngContact], [StartDate], [Status] FROM DELETED 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN
            SET @dmlType = 'Insert'
            INSERT INTO @modifiedRecordsTable SELECT [UniqueID], [lngContact], [StartDate], [Status] FROM INSERTED 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @dmlType = 'Update';
            INSERT INTO @deletedTable SELECT [UniqueID],[lngContact],[StartDate],[Status] FROM DELETED
            INSERT INTO @insertedTable SELECT [UniqueID],[lngContact],[StartDate],[Status] FROM INSERTED
            INSERT INTO @exceptTable SELECT [RowNumber],[UniqueID],[lngContact],[StartDate],[Status] FROM @insertedTable EXCEPT SELECT [RowNumber],[UniqueID],[lngContact],[StartDate],[Status] FROM @deletedTable

            INSERT INTO @modifiedRecordsTable SELECT [UniqueID],[lngContact],[StartDate],[Status] FROM @exceptTable e 
        END
    END

    SELECT @rowsToProcess = COUNT(1) FROM @modifiedRecordsTable    

    BEGIN TRY
        WHILE @rowsToProcess > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @var1 = [UniqueID], @var2 = [lngContact], @var3 = [StartDate], @var4 = [Status]
            FROM    @modifiedRecordsTable
            WHERE   [RowNumber] = @rowsToProcess
                
            IF @dmlType = 'Insert' 
            BEGIN
                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Insert] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dmlType))

                IF @var1 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/UniqueID] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var1))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/UniqueID] (0x)
                END
                IF @var2 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/lngContact] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var2))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/lngContact] (0x)
                END
                IF @var3 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartDate] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var3))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartDate] (0x)
                END
                IF @var4 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/Status] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var4))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/Status] (0x)
                END

                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/EndMessage] (0x)
            END
        
            IF @dmlType = 'Update'
            BEGIN
                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Update] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dmlType))

                IF @var1 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/UniqueID] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var1))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/UniqueID] (0x)
                END
                IF @var2 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/lngContact] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var2))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/lngContact] (0x)
                END
                IF @var3 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartDate] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var3))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartDate] (0x)
                END
                IF @var4 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/Status] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var4))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/Status] (0x)
                END

                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/EndMessage] (0x)
            END

            IF @dmlType = 'Delete'
            BEGIN
                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartMessage/Delete] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dmlType))

                IF @var1 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/UniqueID] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var1))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/UniqueID] (0x)
                END
                IF @var2 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/lngContact] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var2))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/lngContact] (0x)
                END
                IF @var3 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartDate] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var3))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/StartDate] (0x)
                END
                IF @var4 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/Status] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var4))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/Status] (0x)
                END

                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '871bf209-30ab-eb11-8cba-c8d9d20cebfa' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_Appointments_772a313c-6865-4057-95a7-63dc7b7191e3/EndMessage] (0x)
            END

            SET @rowsToProcess = @rowsToProcess - 1
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT

        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState) 
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: This doesn't even look like it should be in a `TRIGGER`. It's going to be awful for performance for any of your DML operations. A `TRIGGER` should have as minimal impact on the transaction and the above will be far from that.

Comment: Don't spam [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) in your code in an attempt to solve your problem (or just generally).

Comment: SMor
what do you mean?

Comment: What's with all the `;SEND ON CONVERSATION...`? Not to sound like Larnu, and I'm surprised they didn't pick up on this, but the `;` character is a statement terminator not a statement begininator.

Comment: @user2777546 Any luck with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

FOR A LONG TIME searching for a solution, I found it [<s>here</s> (Link is broken now)](https://issuehint.com/issue/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency/229#95319462) finally!

Execute this in SSMS (Management Studio) query window:

```
PRINT 'Starting Killing Services'

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(5000) 

DECLARE db_services_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [name] FROM sys.services 
WHERE service_id > 3

OPEN db_services_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_services_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT ('Current Name: ' + @name)
    EXEC('drop service [' + @name + ']')
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_services_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_services_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_services_cursor 

PRINT 'Ended'



PRINT 'Starting Killing Contracts'

DECLARE @contract_name VARCHAR(5000) 

DECLARE db_contract_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [name] FROM sys.service_contracts where service_contract_id > 6

OPEN db_contract_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_contract_cursor INTO @contract_name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT ('Current Name: ' + @contract_name)
    EXEC('drop contract [' + @contract_name + ']')
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_contract_cursor INTO @contract_name 
END 

CLOSE db_contract_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_contract_cursor 

PRINT 'Ended'


PRINT 'Starting Killing Triggers Procs'

DECLARE @triggers_name VARCHAR(5000) 

DECLARE db_triggers_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM sys.triggers WHERE type = 'TR' and name LIKE 'tr_dbo%_Sender'

OPEN db_triggers_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_triggers_cursor INTO @triggers_name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT ('Current Name: ' + @triggers_name)
    EXEC('drop trigger [' + @triggers_name + ']')
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_triggers_cursor INTO @triggers_name 
END 

CLOSE db_triggers_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_triggers_cursor 

PRINT 'Ended'



PRINT 'Starting Killing Stored Procs'

DECLARE @storedprocs_name VARCHAR(5000) 

DECLARE db_storedprocs_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [name] from sysobjects where type = 'P' and category = 0 and name LIKE '%QueueActivationSender'

OPEN db_storedprocs_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_storedprocs_cursor INTO @storedprocs_name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT ('Current Name: ' + @storedprocs_name)
    EXEC('drop PROCEDURE [' + @storedprocs_name + ']')
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_storedprocs_cursor INTO @storedprocs_name 
END 

CLOSE db_storedprocs_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_storedprocs_cursor 

PRINT 'Ended'


PRINT 'Starting Killing Message Types'

DECLARE @messagetype_name VARCHAR(5000) 

DECLARE db_messagetype_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [name] FROM sys.service_message_types where message_type_id > 14

OPEN db_messagetype_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_messagetype_cursor INTO @messagetype_name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT ('Current Name: ' + @messagetype_name)
    EXEC('drop MESSAGE TYPE [' + @messagetype_name + ']')
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_messagetype_cursor INTO @messagetype_name 
END 

CLOSE db_messagetype_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_messagetype_cursor 

PRINT 'Ended'




PRINT 'Starting Killing Queues'

DECLARE @queue_name VARCHAR(5000) 

DECLARE db_queue_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [name] FROM sys.service_queues where is_ms_shipped = 0

OPEN db_queue_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_queue_cursor INTO @queue_name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT ('Current Name: ' + @queue_name)
    EXEC('drop QUEUE [' + @queue_name + ']')
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_queue_cursor INTO @queue_name 
END 

CLOSE db_queue_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_queue_cursor 

PRINT 'Ended'
```

Comment: Hello, I am facing the exact same issue right now. Unfortunatelly the solution link does not work anymore. Could you please describe what was the root cause and why do you need to drop all services?

Comment: It's a weird behavior from the `SqlTableDependency` library, which was obsolete quite a long time ago, and IMHO it is a deadlock caused by this library. Deleting auto-generated procedures and triggers solves it. **It looks like the link is broken**, however, use the code provided in my answer and execute it against your target database.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. It appears when the application is down and the SqlTableDependency stuff must be autocleared. In this case normally the **dbo_TableName_xxxx_QueueActivationSender**, SP will do the job. However if for some reason the trigger is called prior than that it will fail.

The reason is that the Trigger first tries to drop itself and then tries to allocate some variable for the cursor. However this is impossible, because trigger does not exists enymore and that displays the error that object with ID does not exists.

In my case this is happening, because there are multiple instances to a single DB that created multiple triggers to a same table.

So far I found 2 solutions:

1. move the drop trigger statement at the bottom of IF statement (bellow DROp QueueActivationSender procedure )
2. Avoid using the DECLARE variable. Replace it with while (EXISTS SELECT 1 FROm...)

I choose #1 and looks like it works.